Can't cancel heads-up notifications programatically in Android
I have a condition in my code where I have to cancel notifications, inclusing the heads-up notification. The code works for the regular ones, but calling
notificationManager.cancel(notificationId)

does nothing for the heads-up notification. It just dissapears by itself after a few seconds and not before.
Any ideas on why?
